# Do I need a fat jar to use jolly day?

Tags: fatjar

I am using jolly day and i was wondering if i needed a fat jar. Im already implementing it in my build.gradle file

```
implementation group: 'de.focus-shift', name: 'jollyday-core', version: '0.21.0'
implementation group: 'de.focus-shift', name: 'jollyday-jaxb', version: '0.21.0'
```

I created a fat jar for it but the build was failing.